# Restore sound configuration

Tags: 11.10, sound, alsa

After install some packages, I don't have sound! I installed Rosegarden, VMPK (piano software), Drumstick Virtual Piano and TiMidity. At the beginning, all works fine, but when I reset my PC, I don't listen anything.

I would like how can I reinstall Alsa. I want to have it completely new, all the settings by default, for example when Ubuntu is installed.

Comment: Try `sudo alsa force-reload`  or make sure your output device wasn't changed.

Answer (score 2):

Try typing `alsamixer` in terminal and navigate through the options there.

Tip: if any scale has MM under it, it is muted, to enable it just select it (left/right arrows) and press M.

Then if you need to increase or decrease the volume level use up/down arrows.

Comment: Thank you! I only needed to check my sound device and be sure it's the output source.